# Is it possible to filter browser console.log output by console.group?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, console.log

I like the console.group() feature very much.

Is there a way to filter the log using the **group name** as the filter term?

e.g.

```
console.log("I don't want to see this in the log");
console.group("foo");
console.log("I DO want to see this");
console.groupEnd();
console.log("I don't want to see this in the log either");
```

... using the string "foo" I would like to filter out the first and last console.log message.

Is this possible?

I don't want to use a string prefix for my log messages because I will be outputting non-strings (e.g. objects, arrays etc.) which I want to inspect.

Comment: Would it not be easier to prefix console.log using multiple arguments? `console.log('string.prefix.you.can.filter.on',object);`

Comment: If what I am asking is impossible, then that would indeed be infinitely easier.